# How to fill the bottom half of the screen

Tags: xorg, display, software-recommendation

Sometimes I lay down and put the laptop on my chest. In these situations when I need to type, most of the time, I don't see what I'm typing. For example, if I'm using chat software like Element or, when I'm typing in terminal and the cursor is at the bottom of the screen. In this situation, I don't see the cursor because it goes behind my hands while typing. I know this is about laziness, but I want to fix this.

For terminal, I tried to put the cursor always on top, but it broke the output. I didn't like it, as sometimes I lost the start and end of the output.

I was thinking about finding a way to always fill the bottom of the screen (For example, imagine the dock fills half of the screen, or graphic output ignores the bottom half of the screen.), so that the cursor doesn't go down. And I need to switch between these situations (half and full).

Answer (score 0):

This problem sounds a bit esoteric, but why not?

### X/Wayland

Assuming you are in a graphic environment (X, Wayland) - what would stop you to simply size the windows such that it shows on the viewable part only? Then the cursor inside that window cannot go beyond your vision.

If you want harder limits you probably would have to tell X to run the same screen resolution but size the desktop smaller - quite unusual and I am not sure if it is supported at all. If the desktop trick would not work, another angle of attack could be the window manager not sizing/opening windows beyond your line of sight.

### Text Mode

In case you are in text mode, you can use [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) to horizontally split the screen and again configure the upper part to just extend up to your visible range.

Comment: Changing resolution doesn't half the window. It will only stretch the display. But I will test the screen.

Comment: That's why I suggested to configure the desktop size smaller than the screen resolution, but I am not sure if that is possible at all.